# How to create a widget for map function in flutter with buildContext

Tags: flutter, function, dart, flutter-widget

I have this code

```
final users = snapshot.data!;
              return ListView(
                children: users.map(buildMember).toList(),
              );
```

I want to create a widget with **buildConext**

I tried

```
Widget buildMember(Member user, BuildContext context) => Card(
        child: ListTile()
);
```

But got this error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
users.map((user) => buildMember(user, context)).toList(),
```